# How to make a javascript function wait for a javascript function to execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi,

I have this function on jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // jQuery Document
   $(document).ready(function () {
    function loadlog() {
     $.get("logs.html', function (data) {
      $("#container").html(data);
     });
    }
   
    loadlog(); 
   });
  
  //start javascript
  var whatever= something;
</script>
```

I want the javascript part to start right AFTER loadlog(); has finished loading all its stuff so #container wont be empty. Most of the time it does but seems like it will often takes too long in reading the external file and it loads it after the javascript part executes I dont want. What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Where you have `loadLog()` defined, that _is_ where your previous function call has ended and you should add more code. If you want, you could wrap it in a `Promise`, call `resolve` after `loadLoad` and then `await` that promise, but why make it so complicated? You already _know_ the answer.

Comment: no, I dont know it. Thats why I asked.

Comment: "I want the javascript part to start right AFTER loadlog(); " - Yes you do. Put your code _after_.